# ASP.NET, PHP, SQL Server, MySQL hosting provider for developer?

Tags: sql-server, mysql, php, asp.net, web-hosting

I am looking to find a web hosting provider that provides ASP.NET and PHP hosting. The purpose is pretty much just a programming playground for me to develop in and possible show some of my work.

As I use ASP.NET and PHP I am looking for a provider that provides hosting for both of these technologies as well as access to MS SQL Server and MySQL.

Of course I am on a budget so I really can't afford to pay more than $20/month. I had looked at M6.net however in scanning for reviews I found a good deal of negative feedback. I currently use DownTownHost.com and have a good experience with them, however they do not support ASP.NET.

I do not require email hosting though I know most packages include it anyway. Thanks for any suggestions.

Some features that are important to me:

```
* ASP.NET 4 hosting
* ASP.NET MVC support
* PHP
* MySQL
* SQL Server
* URL Rewrite support
* multiple sites under one account
```

Comment: Shopping Questions are Off-Topic on any of the [se] sites. See [Q&A is hard, lets go Shopping](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping) and the [FAQ] for more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend a VPS if you want to just play. A VPS is a virtual server that you can configure to any needs you want and when you want to play with something else just wipe it and install another distribution. I use [linode](http://www.linode.com/?r=707540da8e4c0236bac67ce2fb77df3a96b57778) (referral link) and recommend them. Linode also has great documentation for managing and setting up your VPS [here](http://library.linode.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at 1and1.com

Answer (score 0):

I would just setup a VM on your PC which has the software that you need, or even on your main PC.